# My App Push Notification is not working in my client's iPhone only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, push-notification

I am developing Mobile Application in iOS and I have successfully done creation of push certificates and server side implementation.

Now the problem is, Push Notification is working perfectly in my iPhone 5S and iPhone 6. I have checked it in many phones in India, it's working fine but when I tested it in my client's iPhone 5S then it's not working. After that my client brought another iPhone 5S and gave me his new device UDID, again its not working. Please help me what is wrong.

After lot of googling I found below steps so that our app can ask again for push notification permission.

1. Delete the apps who don't have Push notifications any more form the device.
2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
3. Go to settings and set date and time ahead a day
4. Turn the device off again and turn it back
5. Install the apps again and it'll ask for notification like the first time you installed It.

I followed above steps and device asked for push notification permission but it's still not working in his iPhone.

After that I followed same steps in my iPhone in India in which push notification is already working. After following above steps, my app asked for push notification permission and it's working fine.

Below info may help us in resolving this issue. My Client is in Manchester, United Kingdom  and he is using O2 contract based iPhone.

Comment: You can explicitly change an app's notification settings by going to Settings >  Notifications > Your App and then select the correct option

Comment: Are you using the development or the production certificate?

Comment: Enable push notifications to ur app at settings page..!

Comment: Yes I tried this, but its still not working and I am using Development Certificate @ZeMoon

Comment: Yes Its enabled and My app is asking for Push Notifications permission also in client's phone but not receiving notifications. @Vidhyanand900

Comment: @Gaurav with development certificate you can only receive notification in debug mode.  i-e running directly on your phone using Xcode. For Adhoc and App Store build use production certificate. It will work like charm.

Comment: @Arsalan Yep Just implemented same and Its working fine with production certificates and AdHoc build. Also Thanks for the Perfect Solution, It was working fine on my devices because I was running directly in debug mode. I never thought about it. Thanks Mate !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be using a development's certificate when testing in your phone and using the sandbox server of the apple for the push notifications, and in the client's case its a deployed application using a deployment certificate so you need to remove the sandbox from the push notification's server in your server side and use the live server. It will then work, I once was stuck in the same problem too.
`gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` this is the address for sandbox remove the sandbox from it and you will start getting the notifications on the application that has been made using a deployment's certificate. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have added the Client's UDID in my Developer Account so that it can be used as Testing Device and I am generating IPA using sandbox as my application is still under development. Also as i explained in my question its working fine in my 3 devices based in india but its not working only in Client's Device.

But I'll definitely give a try to your idea and let you know whether it works or not.
but .

Comment: You are super saviour Man !
Now What I did is, Created new Production APNS Certificates instead of Development Certificates, Used gateway.push.apple.com:2195 on Server instead of gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 and Created AdHoc Distribution IPA.

It works like a Charm on client side also !!

Comment: Im glad it helped :) please marks it as the correct answer if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It worked perfectly with the answer suggested by @Ahsan Ebrahim.
Here are the proper steps if we want to test APNS on client's devices.

1. Create Production based APNS Certificate.
2. Use AdHoc as the IPA Distribution because According to Apple AdHoc is used to "Create a distribution provisioning profile to install your app on a limited number of registered devices."
   and iOS App Development : "Create a provisioning profile to install development apps on test devices."

   We have to choose AdHoc here so that we can distribute the IPA.
3. Use production based ck.pem file on server.
4. Use gateway.push.apple.com:2195 on Server instead of gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195.

Code Sign your Application using AdHoc Distribution and you are done.

After that It will work perfectly.

Comment: this is unfair, the person who answered the question should get the credit, not writing your own answer and marking that as the correct answer.

Comment: oops sorry bro, I thought we can tick more than 1. Really sorry. I have marked your answer as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

This is must be issue with the Provisioning file. Please check that you are using right provision when you generate an IPA for your client. I had same issue before that Xcode mistakenly take wildcard mobile provision (Push notification will not work with wildcard mobile provisioning file).The default App ID of my provisioning profile was the auto created "Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID". happy coding .

Comment: Yes I am using my correct provisioning profile and I have added 5 devices. Its working properly in my 3 devices but not working in 2 devices which are Client's Devices